# Display rows to other table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I want to show less rows for print preview.

For example: I have 4 rows in my table(Items) and each row has the same Item no, Item name and Color but the other column (Sizes and Quantity) are not the same.

Is there a way I can show this data into one row to the table?

[image]

I expect each same Item_no shows one row only to the table.

```
<?php       
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM Items";
       $items = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
       while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items)){
       ?>
              <td><?php echo $item['Item_no'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $item['Item_name'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $item['Item_color'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $item['Item_size'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $item['Item_qty'];?></td>
       <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Item_no are the same, you can always group by Item_no and get a SUM of Item_qty

```
$sql = "SELECT Item_no,Item_name,Item_color,Item_size,SUM(Item_qty) FROM Items GROUP BY Item_no";
```

More at,

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-sum-with-group-by.php